# how do I restrict a specific row's columns to have only a specific value set?

Tags: mariadb, check-constraints, mariadb-10.5

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE `mview_state` (
  `state_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'View State ID',
  `view_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'View ID',
  `mode` varchar(16) DEFAULT 'disabled' COMMENT 'View Mode',
  `status` varchar(16) DEFAULT 'idle' COMMENT 'View Status',
  `updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'View updated time',
  `version_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'View Version ID',
  PRIMARY KEY (`state_id`),
  KEY `MVIEW_STATE_VIEW_ID` (`view_id`),
  KEY `MVIEW_STATE_MODE` (`mode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=50 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='View State'
```

With the following data

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=036fb3a69c75a92769a9262ec4af292e

I would like to add a constraint so that when the `view_id` column value is equal to `catalogrule_rule` the `mode` column must be equal to `enabled`

I'm reading and this looks like it would require a check constraint but I'm not sure how to create it so that all other values are valid but this specific condition will always be honored.

So only if the value for `view_id` is `catalogrule_rule` then mode must be set to `enabled`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CHECK Constraint would you not allow to insert or update new rows that have not enabled in mode like the extra insert that i entered.

It would not set it to enabled

> ```
> select version();
> ```
>
> ```
> | version()       |
> | :-------------- |
> | 10.5.11-MariaDB |
> ```

> ```
> create table mview_state
> (
>   state_id int unsigned auto_increment comment 'View State ID'
>       primary key,
>   view_id varchar(255) null comment 'View ID',
>   mode varchar(16) default 'disabled' null comment 'View Mode' 
>   CHECK ((mode = 'enabled' AND view_id = 'catalogrule_rule') OR view_id != 'catalogrule_rule'),
>   status varchar(16) default 'idle' null comment 'View Status',
>   updated datetime null comment 'View updated time',
>   version_id int unsigned null comment 'View Version ID'
> )
> comment 'View State';
>
> create index MVIEW_STATE_MODE
>   on mview_state (mode);
>
> create index MVIEW_STATE_VIEW_ID
>   on mview_state (view_id);
> ```

> ```
> SHOW GRANTS;
> ```
>
> ```
> | Grants for u_1567721770@localhost                                                                                   |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `u_1567721770`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*2E2C82B9AF9ED55252E4DFF4F775075C1D89A8BF' |
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (1, 'design_config_dummy', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:30:05', 0);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (2, 'customer_dummy', 'disabled', 'idle', '2021-03-03 12:06:23', 0);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (3, 'catalog_category_product', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:30:05', 461);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (4, 'catalog_product_category', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:29:03', 98015);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (5, 'catalogrule_rule', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:30:05', 0);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (6, 'catalog_product_attribute', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:30:05', 2310051);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (7, 'cataloginventory_stock', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:30:05', 90478);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (8, 'inventory', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:30:05', 271476);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (9, 'catalogrule_product', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:29:03', 2505904);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (10, 'catalog_product_price', 'enabled', 'working', '2021-06-29 22:30:05', 56676992);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (11, 'amasty_xsearch_category_fulltext', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:29:03', 54687);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (12, 'catalogsearch_fulltext', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:29:03', 2547077);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (33, 'amasty_mostviewed_rule_product', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:29:03', 2);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (34, 'amasty_mostviewed_product_rule', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:29:03', 17980739);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (35, 'amasty_sorting_bestseller', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:29:03', 0);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (36, 'amasty_sorting_most_viewed', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:29:03', 0);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (37, 'amasty_sorting_wished', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:29:03', 0);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (38, 'amasty_yotpo_review', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:30:16', 0);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (43, 'amasty_elastic_relevance_rule_rule', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:29:03', 0);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (44, 'amasty_elastic_relevance_rule_product', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:29:03', 18507058);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (45, 'amasty_elastic_popup_data', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:29:03', 0);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (46, 'amasty_xlanding_product_page', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:29:03', 13596598);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (47, 'amasty_xlanding_page_product', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:29:03', 0);
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (48, 'merchandiser_product_attribute', 'enabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:29:03', 3027849);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mview_state (state_id, view_id, mode, status, updated, version_id) VALUES (5, 'catalogrule_rule', 'disabled', 'idle', '2021-06-29 22:30:05', 0);
> ```
>
> ```
> CONSTRAINT `mview_state.mode` failed for `db_1567721770`.`mview_state`
> ```

> ```
> select * from mview_state;
> ```
>
> ```
> state_id | view_id                               | mode     | status  | updated             | version_id
> -------: | :------------------------------------ | :------- | :------ | :------------------ | ---------:
>        1 | design_config_dummy                   | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:30:05 |          0
>        2 | customer_dummy                        | disabled | idle    | 2021-03-03 12:06:23 |          0
>        3 | catalog_category_product              | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:30:05 |        461
>        4 | catalog_product_category              | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:29:03 |      98015
>        5 | catalogrule_rule                      | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:30:05 |          0
>        6 | catalog_product_attribute             | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:30:05 |    2310051
>        7 | cataloginventory_stock                | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:30:05 |      90478
>        8 | inventory                             | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:30:05 |     271476
>        9 | catalogrule_product                   | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:29:03 |    2505904
>       10 | catalog_product_price                 | enabled  | working | 2021-06-29 22:30:05 |   56676992
>       11 | amasty_xsearch_category_fulltext      | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:29:03 |      54687
>       12 | catalogsearch_fulltext                | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:29:03 |    2547077
>       33 | amasty_mostviewed_rule_product        | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:29:03 |          2
>       34 | amasty_mostviewed_product_rule        | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:29:03 |   17980739
>       35 | amasty_sorting_bestseller             | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:29:03 |          0
>       36 | amasty_sorting_most_viewed            | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:29:03 |          0
>       37 | amasty_sorting_wished                 | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:29:03 |          0
>       38 | amasty_yotpo_review                   | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:30:16 |          0
>       43 | amasty_elastic_relevance_rule_rule    | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:29:03 |          0
>       44 | amasty_elastic_relevance_rule_product | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:29:03 |   18507058
>       45 | amasty_elastic_popup_data             | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:29:03 |          0
>       46 | amasty_xlanding_product_page          | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:29:03 |   13596598
>       47 | amasty_xlanding_page_product          | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:29:03 |          0
>       48 | merchandiser_product_attribute        | enabled  | idle    | 2021-06-29 22:29:03 |    3027849
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=8c9c1acb63d4262690fcce2b8376e109)*

Comment: Ah it was so simple. Thank you very much. The example was doing it with a function on the docs that's why I was a bit confused.

Comment: @gabtzi you might want to give a meaningful  name to the constraint? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=a63ffc9fbf0be48c14c8b9d7131c7369

Comment: The `mode` column is defined as nullable and your constraint allows inserting 'catalogrule_rule' with a null mode, see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=abdf3daaa032a838a67b64ffcffe9344). Perhaps some of these columns, including `view_id` and `mode`, simply shouldn't be nullable, and if they weren't, your constraint would work (in which case you could actually simplify it to `mode = 'enabled' OR view_id <> 'catalogrule_rule'`). However, since they *are* nullable and the requirement is to allow only 'enabled', the constraint probably needs to be able to prevent the nulls.

Comment: In my case I only needed to ensure that the 'catalogrule_rule' column will always have an `enabled` mode and the app makes sure it's not null so the above worked but I see your point. It's good to know